# Passing scripting.dictionary[] by ref to Function

Tags: vbscript

I am working on small VBScript and trying to create `scripting.dictionary[]`. I have to pass that array of dictionary to a function by ref. I got that function through compiled library. the function definition is below.

```
public string Update(string name, ref Scripting.Dictionary[] Data, string sRecordId = "")
```

My lines of code is here

```vb
Set objQWS = CreateObject("Dll")
Set X = PassDictionary

objQWS.Update "Name", x, ""

MsgBox "Additional Info Sent"

Function PassDictionary()
    Dim objDic
    Set objDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    objDic.Add "id", 1
    objDic.Add "name", "a"
    objDic.Add "extd_price", "b"
    objDic.Add "sales_rep", "c"
    objDic.Add "opportunity_id", "d"
    Set PassDictionary = objDic
End Function
```

The problematic area is the `Update` function.
Every time I run the code, on `Update` function it give me the error "type mismatch". can anybody tell me how can I make that thing working?

Comment: Missing the start of the `If` statement.

Comment: There is a If statement, I mistakenly omit that part while pasting my code over here.

Comment: There is a If statement. I missed that while pasting the code. The problem is there in Update function

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a single dictionary, not an array of dictionaries. Try something like

```
Set x = PassDictionary
arr = Array(x)
objQWS.Update "Name", arr, ""
```

Not sure if it'll work, though, since VBScript doesn't really know types, so the array will have the type `Variant()`.

Another thing you could try is to change the type of the parameter from `Scripting.Dictionary[]` to `Scripting.Dictionary`, since you're only passing a single dictionary anyway.

Comment: I have a copy of code that is working in c#. But I'm not able to write the right syntex of vbscript

Comment: somedll.Class crm = new somedll.Class();
            Dictionary[] ar = new Dictionary[1];
            crm.Login("admin", "admin99", "Test");
            
            Dictionary dc = new Dictionary();
            dc.Add("name", "name");
            dc.Add("value", "abc");
            
            ar[0] = dc;
            string sr=crm.CreateOrUpdateRecord("Opportunities", ref ar, "");

Comment: I know but I have to convert that code in vbscript. but don't know how

Comment: I suggested two possible approaches. Did you try any of them?